# Android WebViewClient goes to website in App but will not acknowledge website login

Tags: authentication, webview

I create an Android app that used `webView` to access a website which requires a user's login.  I used the same URL that works in my `Xcode` so I do not know what I missed in authorization or security setting?

My web view activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ActivityBookLesson extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booklesson);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.i-golf.be/lid/app/f?p=101:2");
    }
}
```

The logcat shows the following messages when attempting to enter a user login.

```
09-01 19:46:21.971    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b47ac93 time:1290029286
09-01 19:46:23.391    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-01 19:46:23.521    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:eu.pro_time.internationalgolf time:1290030836
09-01 19:46:23.581    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
09-01 19:46:23.591    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
09-01 19:46:23.591    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
09-01 19:46:23.591    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
09-01 19:46:23.741   9988-10075/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa07a7800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x96895f50
09-01 19:46:23.761    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d64a9f2 time:1290031073
09-01 19:46:24.101    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{33cc6a89 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1b47ac93 {eu.pro_time.internationalgolf/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf.MainActivity}} show : false
09-01 19:46:24.371    9988-9988/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 9988
09-01 19:51:54.931    9988-9996/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.010ms
09-01 19:51:54.971   9988-10008/eu.pro_time.internationalgolf I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27238(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 205(3MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 73MB/80MB, paused 5.732ms total 67.742ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to include the web setting controls.  Adding the following reference information achieved host site's access.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```